# Why Jquery tokeninput value is null?

Tags: jquery, arrays, tokenize, jquery-tokeninput

I have used http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ tokenizer. The array value is always null. This is my code. Can any one tell what is wrong with my code?

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="first" name="first" onchange="callthis()"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#first").tokenInput([
            {name: "Ruby"},
            {name: "Python"},
            {name: "JavaScript"},
            {name: "ActionScript"},
            {name: "Scheme"},
            {name: "Lisap"},
            {name: "C#a"},
            {name: "Fortran"},
            {name: "Visual Basic"},
            {name: "Ca"},
            {name: "C++"},
            {name: "Java"}
        ]);
    });
    </script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/token-input.css" type="text/css" />

<script>
  function callthis(){
    var val = $('#first').tokenInput("get");
    alert(val);
  }
</script>
```

In their documentation they asked to use this line to get the values.`selector.tokenInput("get");`Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried to use the following code:

```
 $("#first").tokenInput([
    {name: "Ruby"},
    {name: "Python"},
    {name: "JavaScript"},
    {name: "ActionScript"},
    {name: "Scheme"},
    {name: "Lisap"},
    {name: "C#a"},
    {name: "Fortran"},
    {name: "Visual Basic"},
    {name: "Ca"},
    {name: "C++"},
    {name: "Java"}
 ]);

  $("#first").change(function(){
     var val = $('#first').tokenInput("get");
  });
```

It works fine. See this sample http://jsfiddle.net/L4oth1d8/3/

Comment: I just added a alert below your variable val, but its showing [Object Object]

Comment: Yes, it is. For example, try to run this `alert({a: 1})`. You will see the same message `[Object Object]`. If you want to print object, use `console.log()`. Be sure, your browser console is opened.